# Splitting a String without .split command

Tags: java

I got a String "1/3" where I want to get only the number 1

Is it possible to get it without using "1/3".split("\\/") ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `indexOf()` and `subString()` to get 1

```
String str = "1/3";
System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("/")));
```

**Must See**

- [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: How would it be?
return string.substring(0,string.indexOf("/"));
this?

Comment: Almost all question you asked answered properly

Answer (score 1):

Read the String API:

```
String.substring(...);
```

Comment: What do you mean unkind? I purposely don't spoonfeed answers so the poster will actually read the API to find out what parameters are required for the method. While reading up on the substring() method they may find other useful methods. Poeple don't learn anything when you spoonfeed answers. Note the posters follow up question to org.life.java's answer? He didn't even take the time to read the API to see how the two suggested methods work! Instead the poster expected to be spoonfed the answer! I'm here to try and help people learn to be problem solvers.

Comment: @camickr: *"Read the String API"* comes across in print as aggressive and dunning. Suggest "Have a look at the String API (link), which has various ways of finding content in strings, like the `indexOf` method." or similar. I'm always suggesting further reading to people when answering questions, I just try to do it kindly. Just my $0.02.

Comment: He is right about it! People want it all easy, so did I, but that's what we want the most.

Comment: I would like to clarify a point here in this case, from time log you can check that initially I just posted that you can use you can use `indexOf()` and `subString()` to get 1 and OP instantly commented below so added whole code , OP knows API . but you are true with your case.

Comment: I know you added the code after the OP asked the follow up question. That is exactly my point. The OP didn't take any time to think about the suggestion or read the API to see what the methods actually do. That is not the way to learn how to program or how to use the API.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, there is no need to include a link to the API. Every programmer should have direct and immediate access to the API. You can't program without a reference to the API.

Comment: @camickr: Whatever. Maybe that's why they're posting questions to a place like SO, they're completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

Or with some regex as well:

```
String s = "1/3";
String m = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)/.+", "$1");
```